# Vistas para cubos

Tags: c#, sql, vistas

Buenas a todos, ¿alguno sabe si será posible crear vistas a partir de un cubo? Es decir, tengo un cubo con muchas métricas y dimensiones, pero tengo muchos usuarios que desean acceder a ver el cubo pero no quieren ver todas las métricas ni todas las dimensiones, entonces quisiera saber si sería posible crear vistas o algo donde solo coloque las métricas y dimensiones que el usuario A quiere, luego otra vista con las métricas y dimensiones que el usuario B quiere, y así sucesivamente.

De momento lo que tengo creado son muchos cubos, uno para cada usuario, pero para hacer cambios a veces resulta tedioso tener que ir uno por uno haciendo las modificaciones.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿estás usando algún producto? Yo tuve experiencia con Oracle BI y básicamente ahí armabas los distintos cubos y los ibas disponibilizando según las necesidades.
La misma herramienta permitía perfilar a que accedía cada usuario.
Si pones el producto que usas, quizás te puedan ayudar mejor.

Comment: Cierto, tienes toda la razon de que no mencioné eso, pues bien, estoy usando microsoft SSAS. Y SQL Sever Data Tools (2012)

Comment: como creas los cubos ? estas usando SQL Server Analysis Services? o como visualizas estos en c#?

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que pretendes se utilizan las Perspectivas.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175338.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167223.aspx

Éxito

Comment: gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @NeyFredJimenez si la repuesta fue de ayuda, marcala como correcta